# Appropriate SELECT Statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following tables:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Subject
(
    Subject_Code      INTEGER,
    Subject_Year      VARCHAR (8),
    PRIMARY KEY (Subject_Code, Subject_Year),
    Teacher_ID INTEGER REFERENCES 
);

CREATE TABLE Teacher
(
    TeacherID        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName         TEXT,
    Department_ID INTEGER References Academic Department(Department_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Subject-taken
(
    Marks_Obtained   INTEGER,
    Subject_Code      INTEGER REFERENCES subject (Subject_Code),
    Candidate_ID       INTEGER REFERENCES Candidate (Candidate_ID),
    PRIMARY KEY (Subject_Code, Candidate_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Academic_Department
(
    Department_ID     INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Department_Name   TEXT
);
```

I've already tried the following select statement

```sql
  SELECT m.subject_code,
         MIN (marks_obtained) AS Min_Marks,
         MAX (marks_obtained) AS Max_Marks
    FROM Subject-taken m, Subject a
GROUP BY m.Subject_Code;
```

Want to use the join function any suggestions on where to use it in order to join the departments with subjects and students

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax! Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server, etc)? And IF you are going to do a comma join (I would use explicit `JOIN`) you need a `WHERE` clause. This smells like MySQL though, which allows you to do some not so great things with aggregation and grouping. To make sure you have accurate data, you'll want to make sure that all of your columns are a) aggregated, or b) in the GROUP BY. If you can't get the correct data because of the grouping, you'll probably need multiple statements.

Comment: I'm using postgress

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: 1) The `Modules.PK` does not match its `Enrollment.FK`.  2) For the files that have `ID` as a "primary key", they will be full of duplicate rows, you need to add  indices to prevent them.  Or make them genuine Relational tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of joins to link your data between tables. Use group by to make statistics by some fields. You can try something like this:

```
SELECT
    Subjects.Subject_Code,
    Subjects.Subject_Name,
    Teachers.TeacherID,
    Academic_Department.Department_ID,
    min(Subject-taken.Marks_Obtained) as min_marks,
    max(Subject-taken.Marks_Obtained) as max_marks,
    avg(Subject-taken.Marks_Obtained) as avg_marks,
    stddev_samp(subject-taken.Marks_Obtained) as stddev_marks
FROM
    Subjects LEFT JOIN
    Teachers ON Subjects.TeacherID = Subjects.TeacherID LEFT JOIN
    Academic_Department ON Teachers.Department_ID = Academic_Department.Department_ID LEFT JOIN
    Subject-taken ON Subjects.Subject_Code = Subject-taken.Subject_Code
GROUP BY
    Subjects.Subject_Code,
    Subject.Subject_Name,
    Teacher.TeacherID,
    Academic_Department.Department_ID
```

I don't really know if `stddev_samp` is the aggregate function you need, `stddev_pop` is also available. Please refer to [this PostgreSQL documentation table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-STATISTICS-TABLE) to find out.